# What event happens when a user re-enters a page through the back button

Tags: html, events, onload

Can someone please tell me what event occurs when a user enters a page by using the back button?  I need to set a value when the user enters the page.  This happens ok when the page is entered fron a nav link. Does it trigger the onload for example?  I need to write a simple javavscript script to handle this.

Comment: Test this. Attach to the onload event and see what happens when clicking back.

Comment: I think it depends: certain events do not get triggered in Opera on navigating back, if I recall correctly.

Comment: It seems to work in FF and IE.  THanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onload()` event, as you thought.

Comment: Thank you answering quickly.  In what order does this happen.  I have some vbscript doing some work before the page opens and the value I need to set is used by this code.  The <body onload=..> comes after this script.